# Proof that $0=1$?

Tags: fake-proofs

I recently saw the following "proof" online, and couldn't pinpoint where the mistake was made:

---

From a well known property, $$1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}.$$

Multiplying both sides by $-1,$ we get $$-1-2-3-\cdots = \frac{1}{12}.$$

We can thus rearrange these equations as follows:

\begin{align*}
1+2+3+4+\cdots= \, -\frac{1}{12}
\\
-1-2-3-\cdots= \; \: \, \, \frac{1}{12}
\\
-1-2-3-\cdots= \; \: \, \, \frac{1}{12}
\\
1+2+\cdots =  -\frac{1}{12}
\end{align*}
Adding, the RHS clearly sums to $0$, while the LHS yields $1$, seemingly yielding that $0=1$. Where did this proof go wrong?

Comment: So you have no problems with your starting assumption?

Comment: "From a well known property": $1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}.$.  What property is that?

Comment: Wow... Amazing 'well-known property'

Comment: Someone came from a numberphile video I see

Comment: Your summing is quite erroneous.  You get 0 = 0.

Comment: This is the first $0=1$ proof that I have seen with a starting assumption that is as unconvincing as the conclusion.

Comment: @Michael and yet it is well-known

Comment: This thing again?

Comment: @Randall This "equation" will occur over and over again on this site.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Unfortunately, I must agree.

Comment: Any method that sums $1+2+3+\dots$ cannot be stable, i.e. you cannot shift the terms back and forth.

Answer (score 7):

The “well known” property is derived from Ramanujan summations, in which divergent sums are treated differently than normal, but then you treat the divergent sum in a typical manner. Plus being able to rearrange the terms and get the same sum is something reserved for absolutely convergent series, which the LHS is not.

Comment: This is the most insightful answer! To add some precision: @AlbonWu implicitly assumes that there is a summability method that meets three criteria: (1) It assigns $-1/12$ to the series. (2) It is *linear*, respecting adding series term by term. (3) It is *stable*, respecting shifting the series to the right. But there is no such method. In particular, Ramanujan summation satisfies (1) and (2) but not (3). Meanwhile, the "typical manner" summation of convergent series satisfies (2) and (3) but not (1).

Answer (score 6):

I think a lot of people have been confused by the "well known property" that you are mentioning, so I am going to elaborate a little bit.

First of all, it is not true that
$$
1+2+3+\dots = -\frac{1}{12}.
$$
And the above shouldn't be true. After all, it doesn't make any sense!

I will briefly explain why you see this identity in a lot of places. Basically, there is a function known as the zeta function which is of particular importance in number theory. For all numbers $s>1$, the zeta function is given by the formula
$$
\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots
$$
If you were to pick $s\leq 1$, the the above sum would be divergent and $\zeta$ would not be well defined.

On the other hand, the function $\zeta$ can be extended to the real line in a meaningful way (this is known as analytic continuation and if taught in undergraduate complex analysis courses). So, we have function $\zeta$ which is defined for all numbers $s$ and such that
$$
\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots
$$
whenever $s>1$.

Now, it turns out that $\zeta(-1) = -1/12$. Plugging $s=-1$ into
$$
\frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots
$$
one would obtain
$$
1+2+3+\dots
$$
This is where your "well known identity" comes from.

Comment: +1: nice answer: a summary is that we have two limiting processes here (limit of a series and limit of a continuous function as its argument tends to a point) and the order of carrying out the processes is important: sum-then-limit-of-function converges but limit-of-functions-then-sum diverges.

Comment: @Quoka "And the above shouldn't be true. After all, it doesn't make any sense!" It does make sense, unless you dogmatically assume Cauchy summation is the only kind of summation that "makes sense".

Answer (score 5):

You start from a Ramanujan summation. In the next steps you use **linearity** (multiplication with $-1$ as well as termwise addition), **stability** (extracting finitely many summands is allowed), and **regularity** (for the convergent series of all $0$ terms, Ramanujan summation yields $0$). Can you justify that Ramanujan summation is linear, stable, and regular?

There *are* [summation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Classical_summation_methods) that are stronger than standard summation (=limit of partial sum), for example Cesàro summation. However, none of these assigns a finite value to $\sum n$, and your argument shows exactly the reason why a finite value is not possible for such a summation method.

Answer (score 4):

*I couldn't pinpoint where the mistake was made...*

In order to understand the original fake proof, I suggest you start with this one, which is simpler:

> From a well known property, $$1+2+3+\cdots = \infty.$$
>
> Multiplying both sides by $-1,$ we get $$-1-2-3-\cdots = -\infty.$$
>
> We can thus rearrange these equations as follows:
>
> \begin{align*}
> 1+2+3+4+\cdots&= \infty\\
> \\
> -1-2-3-\cdots&= -\infty\\
> \\
> -1-2-3-\cdots&= -\infty\\
> \\
> 1+2+\cdots &=  \infty
> \end{align*}
> Adding, the RHS clearly sums to $0$, while the LHS yields $1$, seemingly yielding that $0=1$.

Can you find the mistake for this one?

Answer (score 2):

The "well-known property" that you mention in the beginning does not hold. Therefore, neither does anything that you state after that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at least we have that
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n=-\frac{1}{12} \implies 1=0$$
Is true.

Comment: True I suppose since $p \implies ((\mbox{ not } p) \implies q)$.

Comment: Even this is hard to argue because it uses a false statement in the arrangement of the elements of the series. I just didn't call it out explicitly because it's possible the very same fallacy is used to prove the erroneous starting statement, which leaves me conflicted.

Comment: What do you mean, @Michael?

Comment: @Botond : Oh, well I suppose I should then ask what do _you_ mean in your above answer?  I assumed you were using the logical fact $p \implies ((not p) \implies q)$ (if we know something is both true and false, then anything is true). In this case I thought you were taking $p,q$ propositions defined as $p = \{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n \neq -1/12\}$ and $q = \{1=0\}$.

Comment: @GitGud I think the correctness of the manipulations do not matter. The base statement is false, so he can "derive everything from it".

Comment: Of course, but that lies on the knowledge that the antecedent is false. I'm speaking from the POV of someone who doesn't know that, like the OP (doubt it, TBH). Think of all the statements of the form "If the RH holds, then yada, yada, yada".

Comment: @Michael I just wanted to point out that the truth value of $p \implies q$ is always true when the truth value of $p$ is false.

Comment: @Botond : Yes that is in the same spirit as my first comment, which means I correctly got your point after all.

Comment: @GitGud I'm not certain if I understand you for 100% and I don't want to waste your time, but I think the others pointed out the problems I did not. My goal is/was just to point out the potential danger on $\implies$.

Comment: @Michael Yes, sorry. It confused me a bit. Sadly, $\text{I'm good at mathematical logic} \implies 1=0$ as well.

Comment: @Botond : That is funny.  I liked this answer best, I'm sorry somebody downvoted it (likely they didn't understand the logic).

Comment: @Michael I downvoted it because the the implication is false. The antecedent is true but the consequent is false.

Comment: @user76284 $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n=-\frac{1}{12}$ is clearly false.

Comment: @Botond What do you mean? It’s false if you’re restricting yourself to Cauchy summation, but more powerful summation methods exist.

Comment: @user76284 $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n=\lim_n \sum_{i=0}^n a_i$, by definition. But we could say the same about the rhs as well, couldn't we? $1=0$ is false if we restrict ourselves to the standard equality, but we surely can define a new one where it is true.

Comment: “by definition” Not really. This is like saying “$2^\pi$ doesn’t exist because $2^x$ is defined as $\prod_{n=1}^x 2$ which doesn’t make sense when $x=\pi$”. The point is that there’s a natural extension of this operation and it makes perfect sense to refer to it likewise.

Comment: “But we could say the same about the rhs as well, couldn't we?” The difference is that stronger summation methods are consistent with Cauchy summation (they assign the same values to Cauchy-convergent series), whereas $0=1$ isn’t.

Comment: Imagine if you insisted on using a different symbol for addition of natural numbers, integers, real numbers, complex numbers, vectors, functions, etc.

Comment: @user76284 Why would Ramanujan summation be a "natural extension"?

Comment: @Botond You don't need Ramanujan summation to derive $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -1/12$. You only need to observe that -1/12 is the (unique!) value obtained by analytically continuing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^s$ to $s=1$. You can also use the limit approach I describe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327812/limit-approach-to-finding-1234-ldots).

Comment: @user76284 Yes, if we define $f$ for $\Re(x)>1$ as $f(x)=\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{1}{n^x}$, then we, in fact, can assign a value to $f(-1)$ with analytical continuation. But it will not be the value of $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{1}{n^{-1}}$, because the sum does not converge.

Comment: @Botond Like I said, the fact that a series doesn't converge in the Cauchy sense doesn't mean it doesn't have a value. A series can have a value it doesn't Cauchy-converge to.

Comment: @user76284 Yes, you can extend it as you wish. You can do whatever you want. What if I'd like to assign the value $42$ to all of the divergent sums? I could do it, couldn't I? But it would no longer be the "casual sum", so it would not necessarily possess the properties of the "casual sum". And I'd say that about 99% of the people are using the $\sum$ symbol to denote the limit of the partial sums, so it's not a great idea to use it for a different thing without saying it.

Comment: @user76284 And if the $\sum$ is not the limit of the partial sums, then it's also bad to say that "$1+2+3+...=-\frac{1}{12}$", because as you said, the $\sum$ is not the limit of the partial sums, but the lhs is meant to be that. It's like saying that I define $\sum_n a_n$ as $\lim_n a_n$, and then complaining about $\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...=0$ is not true.

Comment: @Botond "What if I'd like to assign the value 42 to all of the divergent sums?" That definition is not consistent with Cauchy-summation. "the lhs is meant to be that" Only if you restrict yourself to Cauchy-summation. "It's like saying that I define $\sum_n a_n$ as $\lim_n a_n$" That definition is also not consistent with Cauchy-summation.

Comment: @user76284 Why would my "42-sum" be inconsistent with the Cauchy-summation? It'd assign the same value to the convergent sequences and $42$ to the divergent ones. Why is it different from your Ramanujan sum?

Comment: @Botond $0 = \sum_n 0 = \sum_n (n + (-n)) = \sum_n n + \sum_n (-n) = 42 + 42 = 84$

Comment: @Botond "Why is it different from your Ramanujan sum?" I never mentioned a Ramanujan sum.

Comment: @user76284 I don't see the "problem" with your derivation of 0=84. $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n = -\frac{1}{12}$ would also mean that $0=1$, as you can see in the question because you are using the properties of a different function. Why do you expect that it will work?

Comment: @Botond $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -1/12$ does not imply $0=1$. In fact, your method is even worse than I described because it violates homogeneity: $42 = \sum_n 2n = 2 \sum_n n = 2 \cdot 42 = 84$.

Comment: @user76284 I think I've had enough of your sigmas. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Botond Could you explain why you think my manipulation can be used to derive $0=1$ from $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -1/12$? To derive the contradictions, I only used additivity (in fact, subadditivity alone suffices) in my first example and positive homogeneity in my second example. The OP, on the other hand, is using the property of stability, which *cannot* be satisfied by any method capable of summing certain kinds of series (like the one in the OP) and thus can never belong to any "complete" or "sufficiently powerful" theory of summation.